# Youtube API - API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key

Tags: youtube-api

I have the API key activated with no restrictions.
But still I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I'm using this request:
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[VIDEO-ID]&key=[MY-KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=%5BVIDEO-ID%5D&key=%5BMY-KEY%5D)

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you generated an API key and are you passing it instead of `[MY-KEY]`?

Comment: Where did you get the key, exactly?  You need one created on Google developer console.  Not google cloud console.

Comment: Does your API key satisfy the regex `^AIzaSy[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{33}$`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses!
I replaced [MY-KEY] with the key generated in https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: hi, im having the same issue `url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+API_KEY+"&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=200'

response = requests.get(url).json()` i passed the key in directly and still invalid, key activated non restricted,
anybody has any suggestion?